# How to apply a filter with FP/scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a class that has some `Option` values, and I need to apply all the values that come as `Some` in the class to a list of objects.

Example:

```
class Thing(name: String, age: Int)
class Filter(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int], size: Option[Int])
val list: List[Thing] = functionThatReturnsAListOfThings(param)
val filter: Filter = functionThatReturnsAFilter(otherParam)
list.filter{ thing => 
  if filter.name.isDefined {
    thing.name.equals(filter.name.get)
  }
  if filter.age.isDefined {
    thing.age == filter.age.get
  }
}.take{
  if filter.size.isDefined filter.size.get
  else list.size
}
```

How can I apply the filter to the list properly with FP?

Comment: what is wrong about this code?

Comment: for me it feels imperative, not sure if I'm doing it using FP

Comment: then it's not entirely functional - you're passing `Filter` as object

Answer (score 1):

First off we need to make a small change so that the constructor arguments are public members.

```
class Thing(val name: String, val age: Int)
class Filter(val name : Option[String]
            ,val age  : Option[Int]
            ,val size : Option[Int])
```

Next, it's not clear, from your example code, what should happen when `filter.name` and `filter.age` are both `None`. I'll assume that `None` means `true`, i.e. not filtered out.

```
list.filter { thing =>
  filter.name.fold(true)(_ == thing.name) &&
    filter.age.fold(true)(_ == thing.age)
}.take(filter.size.getOrElse(Int.MaxValue))
```

Note that `take(Int.MaxValue)` is a bit more efficient than `take(list.size)`.

Comment: you are right. meant to use `case class` instead. And yes, when the field in the Filter is `None` then it is not a criteria for you to filter the list.